# Output result set in a PL/pgSQL script

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, resultset

I have a PL/pgSQL script (not a function or procedure), which does a bunch of work. Is it possible to display the output of a `SELECT` statement?

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10;
END $$;
```

Error:

> ERROR: query has no destination for result data
>
> Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

I understand that it doesnt make much sense for a procedure or function to have a select statement like this, but for a simple script I think it makes sense to be able to see the data you're working with, even if only for debugging.

Is this possible?

Comment: 1) As the error message says you need `PERFORM` not `SELECT` per [Executing SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-GENERAL-SQL) . 2) Per [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html): *The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void.*. Reading the docs is helpful.

Comment: Using `PERFORM` doesnt capture the results, though. Or at least I cant see them in my DB app (DBeaver). Maybe this is a DBeaver issue, I'll try with PGAdmin and report back

Comment: Same in PGAdmin - `PERFORM` may execute the query, but it doesnt show me the results, so I dont think it'll help me with this, unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Read the links I posted. It really doesn't matter what you do in `DO` it will not return anything.

Comment: You could use RAISE to get some output during the processing of some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense for a function to run a query like that, and it is easy to write a function that returns the result set:

```
CREATE FUNCTION xyz() RETURNS SETOF my_table
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10;
END;$$;
```

But a procedure or a `DO` statement don't return anything, so the only thing you can do is loop through the result set and send a `NOTICE` or `INFO` message to the client:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10
   LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '%', r;
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```